# Python Django: Inline edit and sub-total automatic

Tags: python, django, forms, inline-editing

I have a simple application for forecasting hours in projects for team members. The 'view' mode:
[image]

For the "edit" mode I have this interface:
[image]

Instead of a new view/template for "edit" I would like to have inline edit functionality. Is that feasible with Python Dango only as I don't want to use jquery or JavaScript.

Similarly, can the sub-total be calculated automatically on the page just using Python Django?

Comment: How do you see inline editing being different from just using your edit template instead of your view one?  Also, you won't be able to update things on the page without some sort of javascript, though a js library like HTMX might assist in a low-code sort of way.

Comment: The inline edit appears to be a more 'modern' user experience. Thanks for the clarification on the need for javascript.

Comment: There are a couple of django modules for inline editing (eg, https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=django+inline+edit&s=updated&type=Repositories) but, again, they all require JS or Jquery. Anthing that passes information back to the server without submitting a form (and thus reloading a page) will require something of that sort.